# Unity Android build corrupt file / App not installed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

[image]

I am creating a mobile app using the Unity engine (2020.3.46f1 Personal)
I am running into an issue when attempting to build the app and install it onto my cellphone for testing, I get the error "App not installed". Below is my External Sources (image). They are all the Unity defaults. The project was a Unity Mobile 2D preset.

Comment: any more on the error message?

Comment: @pixlhero I dont recall having any errors in my Unity console after building, but I will retry and see what it says. When installing all it does is show a popup that says "Something went wrong. App not installed"

Comment: maybe try deleting the app on the phone (if I remember correctly, that was more of an iOS issue though...)

Comment: @pixlhero. I cant delete the app on the phone, because it was never installed. I havent even been able to get a single version of the app installed

Comment: hmm. did you activate the developer options you need to? USB Debugging for example.

Comment: @pixlhero Im sending the file wirelessly. I just created a new blank unity project and attempted to build and install, and it has the same issue. It is blank and has nothing in it. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253112/discussion-between-pixlhero-and-ghostplays74).

Comment: Try to install the build via the adb. It usually shows concrete errors.

Comment: @Morion, Thank you for the advice. What is "the adb" though? (Sorry if its obveous and Im ment to know)

Comment: Actually, it can be easily found with google. https://developer.android.com/tools/adb

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved by downloading a new version of Unity. The issue occured on version 2020.3, updating to version 2021.3 fixed it